# How can you decipher a stack trace with only numbers and no method names?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stack-trace

The application I'm working on is getting these mysterious crashes in the field. For some reason, our logging doesn't record anything useful for this issue.  All we get is this stack trace, which apparently just has a bunch of numbers instead of method names, etc.

Is there a way to map these numbers back to something useful for tracking down the issue? Thanks!

> ********************************************* Session: 8D7D3FB4-47DB-4840-9CDE-6E81CBBCACDD Message: *** -[NSArray
>   getObjects:range:]: range {16, 7} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 6]
>
> StackTrace Information
>
> ---
>
> (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182247d50
>    + 148  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x000000018175c528 objc_exception_throw + 56  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001821e0c44 _CFArgv + 0    3   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000018217be90 CFUniCharMapCaseTo + 0     4   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000018217bcac redacted + 220     5   kmb
>   0x0000000100cf5300 kmb + 1889024  6   kmb
>   0x0000000100db7de8 kmb + 2686440  7   kmb
>   0x0000000100db9208 kmb + 2691592  8   kmb
>   0x0000000100db6738 kmb + 2680632  9   kmb
>   0x0000000100db5c78 kmb + 2677880  10  kmb
>   0x0000000100db58b0 kmb + 2676912  11  kmb
>   0x0000000100bddd7c kmb + 744828   12  kmb
>   0x0000000100b9e8b4 kmb + 485556   13  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000181bcd088 redacted + 24  14  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000181bcd048 redacted + 16  15  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000181bd4090 redacted + 716     16  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000181bda1c8 redacted + 596     17  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000181bd9f10 redacted + 120     18  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x0000000181e73130 _pthread_wqthread + 1268   19 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000181e72c30 start_wqthread
>
> ### + 4 )

Comment: Search for threads about "symbolicatecrash".  It's an Xcode utility for making the translations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can perform crash log symbolication which is the process of transforming active memory addresses into a human readable format like method or function names.
For details, you check this link:

[https://medium.com/@iboudhayan/understanding-of-crash-log-symbolication-a0c00c6e86f0](http://Crash%20Log%20Symbolication)

Comment: Thanks!  However, the steps don't seem to work for me.  When I go to Windows -> Devices and simulators -> View Device Logs  and try to drag my .crash file, nothing happens.  It seems like this panel doesn't accept drag and drop files